# Can i use a dropdown in ui-grid filling it with data from a database?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grid, angular-ui-grid

I'm facing some issue here when i try to use a dropdown inside a ui-grid passing to it fields from a database. Following the [docs](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable), in the gridOptions.columnDefs, i have create an array of id and a value, like:

```
{ name: 'gender', displayName: 'Gender', editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor', width: '20%',
  cellFilter: 'mapGender', editDropdownValueLabel: 'gender', editDropdownOptionsArray: [
  { id: 1, gender: 'male' },
  { id: 2, gender: 'female' }
] },
```

but, in my case the "id" and the "value", must be fields from the database, as follows:

```
 { id: data.Id, gender: data.Nome }
```

It just don't work. Any ideas about how to solve this?
Thanks!!

Comment: You will need to provide more code for us to be able to help you. How are you getting your data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider using [Angular Grid](http://www.angulargrid.com/) - it allows you to have custom cell renderers, where you can have a cell renderer that's interactive. I have it working in my job (can't post the code example as it belongs to the company I work for) however if this is an option I can mock something up and post it.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor', 
editDropdownOptionsArray: YourDataArray, 
editDropdownIdLabel: 'Id', 
editDropdownValueLabel: 'Nome'
```

YourDataArray could be a service call - for example, for me I have a call to MyServiceName.Get() - the objects returned might have properties like 'Id' and 'Nome' as in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach. It was based on this thread:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/issues/2808

1) I defined an uiGridFactory.js as this one:

```
angularFactories.factory('uiGridFactory', function ($http, $rootScope) {

var factory = {};

/* It returns a dropdown filter to help you show editDropdownValueLabel
 *
 * Parameters:
 *
 * - input: selected input value, it always comes when you select a dropdown value
 * - map: Dictionary containing the catalog info. For example:
 *    $scope.languageCatalog = [ {'id': 'EN', 'description': 'English'}, {'id': 'ES', 'description': 'Español'} ]
 * - idLabel: ID label. For this example: 'id'.
 * - valueLabel: Value label. For this example: 'description'.
 *
 * 1) Configure cellFilter this way at the ui-grid colDef:
 *
 * { field: 'languageId', name: 'Language'), editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
 *   editDropdownIdLabel: 'id', editDropdownValueLabel: 'description', 
 *   editDropdownOptionsArray: $scope.languageCatalog,
 *   cellFilter: 'mapDropdown:row:row.grid.appScope.languageCatalog:"id":"description":languageCatalog' },
 *
 * 2) Append this snippet to the controller:
 * 
 * .filter('mapDropdown', function(uiGridFactory) { 
 *    return uiGridFactory.getMapDrowdownFilter()
 * });
 *
 */
factory.getMapDrowdownFilter = function() {

    return function(input, map, idLabel, valueLabel) {

        if (map != null)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < map.length; i ++) {
                if (map[i][idLabel] == input)
                {
                    return map[i][valueLabel];
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
}

return factory;

});
```

2) Then I added the filter mapDropdown at the end of the controller that requires dropdown logic

```
.filter('mapDropdown', function(uiGridFactory) { 
    return uiGridFactory.getMapDrowdownFilter()
});
```

3) I added this cellFilter to the column definition that contains the dropdown:

```
 columnDefs: [
     { field: 'id', 'ID')},
     { field: 'languageId', name: 'Language',
           editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor', 
           editDropdownIdLabel: 'id', editDropdownValueLabel: 'description', 
           editDropdownOptionsArray: $scope.languageCatalog,
           cellFilter: 'mapDropdown:row.grid.appScope.languageCatalog:"id":"description"' },
     { field: 'comments', 'Comments' }
 ]
```

where the mapDropdown() parameters are:

a) the catalog map (row.grid.appScope.languageCatalog)

b) the ID label

c) the VALUE label

Note: In my example I used $scope.languageCatalog variable that was loaded from Database with a factory. You have to implement your own.

```
factory.getLanguages = function (callback) {

    $http.get(RESOURCES.REST_ADDRESS + 'getLanguages').
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

            callback(data);
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        });
}
```

Comment: @Auiles, my actual issue was different,but this post helped me to figure that out. My id/values are purely dynamic and was an issue while saving it after editing.